80s/90s horror(/comedy?) w/Ziggy Stardust costumed heroine
I am looking (without much success) for the title of a certain horror film. Here are some plot points I remember:

A group of teens gather in a peculiar house dressed in costume (so either Halloween or a costume party of some kind). Lead girl is wearing a shiny silver Ziggy Stardust-style costume. Another girl is dressed as a slutty angel.
One of the girls stops pretending to be stupid (either angel or Ziggy).
An Asian girl is seduced by a china doll, they kiss and the china doll sucks out her tongue, drawing her in. Eventually, the girl becomes the china doll.
Other poltergeist-ish things happen as other teens die off and Ziggy-girl ends up kicking ass.

Any ideas?

Edit1: the movie was made in America and in English.
Edit2: I seem to remember a male teen or teacher controlling the evil occurrences behind the scenes.


Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification.What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
